# Getting drawable area of an AWT frame in Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, graphics, awt, paint

I have subclassed [`java.awt.Frame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html) and have overridden the [`paint()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#paint-java.awt.Graphics-) method as I wish to draw the entire contents of the window manually.

However, on the graphics object, (0,0) corresponds to the upper left hand corner of the window **inside** the title bar decoration, not the first drawable pixel.

Can I determine the co-ordinate of the first drawable pixel (ie, the height of the decoration) in a cross-platform manner, avoiding using a Mac OS X-specific [fudge factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fudge_factor)? Will I be forced to nest a [Panel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Panel.html) component in order to find the actual drawable area of the window?

Here, my code fails to centre the blue square inside the paintable area of the window:

```
@Override
public void paint (Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.setPaintMode();
    g.fillRect(30, 30, getWidth()-60, getHeight()-60);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the frame insets by calling the getInsets method (defined in Container). Frame insets are discussed at the top of the Frame API docs.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to paint the whole area and don't want a title bar at all?

Assuming that you use JDk 1.4 (at least) then you can declare the frame to be "undecorated" (java.awt.Frame#setUndecorated(boolean)). This way no title bar is created and therefore the frames-paintable area is the same as the frames-consumed area.