# How Do You Get the Height of the Titlebar Using Java (Swing)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am getting a `MouseEvent` in Java.  the `getPoint()` method is adding the height of the title bar into the y portion of the coordinate.

I was wondering how I can find the height of the title bar of the current window in order to offset the y value by the correct amount.

Comment: Do you think you could post some (preferably simplified) code that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: I figured out my problem..I added the motion listener to the frame and not the panel.  Oops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the frame insets by calling the getInsets method (defined in Container). Frame insets are discussed at the top of the Frame API docs. [See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193457/getting-drawable-area-of-an-awt-frame-in-mac-os-x)

Of course you could always add your mouse listener to the content pane. JFrame has some unexpected behaviour on some methods such as `add` and `setLayout`.